# Настройка prettier в html

Tags: html, css

Кто может сталкивался, как можно настроить так,

```
<div class="header__top" style='background-image: url("img/main-bg.jpg");'>
```

чтобы у данного дива, путь внутри прописывался в двойных кавычках, а остальное в одинарных, чтобы никто не конфликтовал.
Настройки prettier:

```
module.exports = {
    trailingComma: 'es5',
    tabWidth: 4,
    semi: false,
    singleQuote: true,
}
```

Comment: `style="background-image: url('img/main-bg.jpg');"` попробуйте наоборот, аттрибуты должны заключаться в двойные кавычки, а уже внутренние параметры в одинарные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё понял, проблема в stylelint, он линтерит html, и по итогу получается конфликт кавычек.
"background-image: url("img/main-bg.jpg");"